# Ethernet over USB not working for Linux Kernel (3.14.35)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ethernet, usbserial

I am working with the Linux Kernel v3.14.35. In which i need to provide Ethernet over USB support.

I made the modification in the Kernel configuration. It works fine.

I got the interface up from both the side as the name of `usb0`.

I configured the IP Address and try to ping. I found some crash and following backtrace i got.

> ```
> [  153.356767] c0 1601 (ifconfig) ------------[ cut here ]------------
> [  153.363079] c0 1601 (ifconfig) WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1601 at kernel/workqueue.c:1393 __queue_work+0x254/0x368()
> [  153.373077] Modules linked in: g_ether usb_f_rndis usb_f_ecm_subset usb_f_ecm libcomposite u_ether
> [  153.382104] c0 1601 (ifconfig) CPU: 0 PID: 1601 Comm: ifconfig Not   tainted 3.14.35 #7
> [  153.389963] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0016db4>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012e78>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
> [  153.399371] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0012e78>] (show_stack) from [<c0758af0>] (dump_stack+0x7c/0xbc)
> [  153.408254] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0758af0>] (dump_stack) from [<c002a754>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x70/0x8c)
> [  153.418000] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c002a754>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c002a80c>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24)
> [  153.428441] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c002a80c>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0042218>] (__queue_work+0x254/0x368)
> [  153.438365] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0042218>] (__queue_work) from [<c0042374>] (queue_work_on+0x48/0x54)
> [  153.447682] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0042374>] (queue_work_on) from [<c03e5f24>] (done+0x110/0x1b0)
> [  153.456474] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c03e5f24>] (done) from [<c03e8aac>] (mv_udc_irq+0x75c/0xf20)
> [  153.465010] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c03e8aac>] (mv_udc_irq) from [<c0075820>] (handle_irq_event_percpu+0x6c/0x298)
> [  153.475112] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0075820>] (handle_irq_event_percpu) from [<c0075a88>] (handle_irq_event+0x3c/0x5c)
> [  153.485638] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0075a88>] (handle_irq_event) from [<c0078960>] (handle_fasteoi_irq+0x84/0x14c)
> [  153.495822] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0078960>] (handle_fasteoi_irq) from [<c0074f7c>] (generic_handle_irq+0x2c/0x3c)
> [  153.506090] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0074f7c>] (generic_handle_irq) from [<c000f8fc>] (handle_IRQ+0x40/0x90)
> [  153.515664] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c000f8fc>] (handle_IRQ) from [<c0008618>] (gic_handle_irq+0x2c/0x5c)
> [  153.524892] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0008618>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c00139c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)
> [  153.534026] c0 1601 (ifconfig) Exception stack(0xec09bdb8 to 0xec09be00)
> [  153.540729] c0 1601 (ifconfig) bda0:                                                       ec219500 a0000013
> [  153.550558] c0 1601 (ifconfig) bdc0: 00000001 00000009 ec219500 ebe78c24 00000000 00000004 ec219510 000000d0
> [  153.560395] c0 1601 (ifconfig) bde0: a0000013 ebe65900 2ec010c0 ec09be00 bf001824 c075e224 20000013 ffffffff
> [  153.570232] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c00139c0>] (__irq_svc) from [<c075e224>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x20/0x54)
> [  153.580511] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c075e224>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore) from [<bf001824>] (rx_fill+0x1e0/0x2ac [u_ether])
> [  153.591656] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<bf001824>] (rx_fill [u_ether]) from [<bf0018fc>] (eth_start+0xc/0x38 [u_ether])
> [  153.601842] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<bf0018fc>] (eth_start [u_ether]) from [<bf001984>] (eth_open+0x5c/0x60 [u_ether])
> [  153.612209] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<bf001984>] (eth_open [u_ether]) from [<c05c83fc>] (__dev_open+0xa8/0x10c)
> [  153.621874] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c05c83fc>] (__dev_open) from [<c05c8684>] (__dev_change_flags+0x94/0x168)
> [  153.631533] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c05c8684>] (__dev_change_flags) from [<c05c8770>] (dev_change_flags+0x18/0x48)
> [  153.641630] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c05c8770>] (dev_change_flags) from [<c06551b4>] (devinet_ioctl+0x7c8/0x89c)
> [  153.651466] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c06551b4>] (devinet_ioctl) from [<c05b0434>] (sock_ioctl+0x130/0x28c)
> [  153.660782] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c05b0434>] (sock_ioctl) from [<c0139898>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3f0/0x5b8)
> [  153.670005] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0139898>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c0139acc>] (SyS_ioctl+0x6c/0x7c)
> [  153.678971] c0 1601 (ifconfig) [<c0139acc>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000f020>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
> [  153.688195] c0 1601 (ifconfig)
> ---[ end trace 165fce7ec193769d ]---
> ```

I am able to ping from device to host but not able to process the Acknowledgement sent from host.

Comment: Try latest vanilla kernel first. If there is still a bug, try linux-next. Even if there is a bug present file a bug report. Otherwise it might be already fixed issue.

Comment: that kernel is already customized. I can not switch to another kernel. I have to work with this kernel version.

Comment: You *have to* try a newest kernel to figure out is the bug *still* in the driver, your code, or somewhere else. Otherwise you are at your own.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I have modified driver for udc(USB Device Controller). So I am able to access ethernet over USB in Linux Kernel 3.14.35.